# Design a synchronous sequential circuit

Tags: flipflop, boolean-algebra

I can't figure out how to do this exercise: (sorry for my bad english)

Design a synchronous sequential network according to the Mealy model with an input and an output which must assume the value 1 when the sequence 000 or sequence 001 or sequence 111 is recognized as an input. The output continues to assume the value 1 whatever are the next sequences.

How can I solve the problem?

I tried with this:[image]

Comment: Make a "I'm outputting a one and I'm not changing my mind" state, which can be entered but not exited from.

Comment: should you use JK flipflops?

Comment: What happens if 101 is input?   Your state machine is not correct.   0 or 1 in state 00 must go different states.   A 1 is the first state in 111.  A 0 is first state in 000 or 001.

Comment: So i need 5 state not 4?

Comment: You need 6.  Don't forget feedback states. A 110 would start out on 111 sequence but have to transition to first state of 000 or 001 sequence.

Comment: https://imgur.com/hpSdLet That's an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

From your initial state:

- a 0 sets you on 000 or 001 sequence.
- a 1 sets you on 111 sequence.

[image: State Machine]

This will get you started.  Both end at the same state.

Do not forget alternative states:

- a 01 could be the start of 0111.
- a 10 could be the start of 1000.